# Migration of paypal and stripe subscription to new site

Tags: wordpress, paypal, stripe-payments, subscription, paypal-subscriptions

I have a website with subscription based model, it is podcast website. the thing is the site is divided into two parts , one is front site in WordPress for providing information about the content and another is portal where the customers can login to to get access to the subscription content. now we are moving the portal site to WordPress and keeping just one site, the wordpress site will now handle subscriptions.

I needed help with is how can I migrate all the subscription from the old site to this new site with out affecting any subscription, the domain will remain the same just we will stop the old site.

so far I have migrated the user and their subscription details to WP site which are stored in portal DB.

now need to point all the subscription stored on stripe and PayPal to point to this new site.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `to point all the subscription stored on stripe and PayPal to this new site`. If you're using Stripe Billing, the subscriptions are not linked to your website. You just need to have your new site use the same API keys to query your Account.